# Create nav bar that appears after scrolling to second section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create something like [that](http://www.andreagalanti.it/lab/flatfy/)

What I understand is that no matter the window size, the background is resized to fit perfectly and once I scroll down the nav bar becomes visible and sticks to the top.

I believe I am going to need javascript (?) and obviously HTML and CSS.

Any tips, even to what to search will be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just google something like 'sticky navigation'. Here's the codepen I found (using jquery) and edited:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NABAxd.

The idea is very simple: you attach a handler to `scroll` event to check if user has scrolled down a certain amount. Based on that you apply or remove `position:fixed` to element. And you can find the amount of pixels scrolled from top via `window.pageYOffset`.

EDIT:
You can set `height: 100vh` to first section to cover whole browser window. I have edited the codepen.

Comment: Via window.pageYOffset can I get the size of the window so that I set the background image to that? In the example that you provided there navbar does what I need but is not hidden until scrolled. Or should I ask another question for that?

Comment: right, sorry, let me edit my answer

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, I just meant if I need to create another question as this might be considered a different issue!

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: I did and thank you but the pen seems the same. prntscr.com/bz0sii

Comment: sorry, correct pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NABAxd